# KOTLIN: Finding empty time slots given list of availability for a week and booked appointments

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, appointment

I have two tables for availability for a resource for a week and booked timeslots. I feel the logic of copying the availability into a second MutableList in Kotlin and then looping over the avialable slots and booked slots to remove the booked slots should work. But in my case (code is below), all slots are being removed and as such all slots are visible.

For e.g.
If I have 3 bookable slots for wednesday, say 8 am to 9 am, 9 am to 10.00 am and 10 am to 11.00 am, and the slot at 8 am is now booked, a new user needs to see only the 9 am and 10.00 am slot. But what happens is I see all three slots even if the 8.00 am slot is booked... which is weird... considering that the code seems sound.

Can somebody please guide as to how to do this right?

```
    private fun getUnbookedAppointments(listOfAvailableSlots: MutableList<String>) {
    //get appointments that are already scheduled for this day

    val newAvailableList: MutableList<String> = listOfAvailableSlots.toMutableList()

    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Bookings")
        .whereEqualTo("providerId", serviceProvider!!.getUID())
        .whereEqualTo("date", booking.getdate())
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {

            val existingBookingsList: List<Booking> = it.toObjects(Booking::class.java)

            for (booking in existingBookingsList) {
                //change availability of the time slots
                val startTimeOfExistingBooking = createTime(booking.getstartTime()!!)
                val endTimeOfExistingBooking = createTime(booking.getstartTime()!!)
                //add duration to time
                servDuration = booking.getduration()!!.toInt()
                getHrsMins(servDuration)
                endTimeOfExistingBooking.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, durhrs)
                endTimeOfExistingBooking.add(Calendar.MINUTE, durmins)

                for (slot in listOfAvailableSlots) {
                    val startTimeofSlots = createTime(slot)
                    val endTimeofSlots = createTime(slot)
                    endTimeofSlots.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,1)

                    if (((startTimeOfExistingBooking.timeInMillis >=  startTimeofSlots.timeInMillis) && (startTimeOfExistingBooking.timeInMillis < endTimeofSlots.timeInMillis))
                        || ((endTimeOfExistingBooking.timeInMillis <=  endTimeofSlots.timeInMillis) && (endTimeOfExistingBooking.timeInMillis > startTimeofSlots.timeInMillis))) {
                        newAvailableList.remove(slot)
                        Log.i("/HELLO Size of new after", "Slot removed")
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.i("BOOK Checked current appointments", "${existingBookingsList.size}")

            if(newAvailableList.size > 0){
                Log.i("BOOK Checked current appointments", "New list is not empty")
                displayAvailableSlotsbyDate(newAvailableList)
            } else {
                Log.i("BOOK Checked current appointments", "New list is empty")
                displayAvailableSlotsbyDate(listOfAvailableSlots)
            }

        }.addOnFailureListener {

            timeSlotsLL!!.removeAllViews()
            findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.nodateFilter).visibility = VISIBLE
            timeSlotsLL!!.visibility = GONE
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.noDatesFiltxt).text = "Sorry, there are no slots available."
            Log.i("BOOK Data recovery of slots from Firestore failed", "$it")
        }
}
```

This is the code I am using to convert a string say 8.00 am to a calendar object with Hour of the day at 8.00 am

```
private fun createTime(time: String): Calendar {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = time.split(":").toTypedArray()[0].toInt()
        calendar[Calendar.MINUTE] =
            time.split(":").toTypedArray()[1].split(" ").toTypedArray()[0].toInt()
        calendar[Calendar.AM_PM] =
            if (time.split(":").toTypedArray()[1].split(" ")
                    .toTypedArray()[1].lowercase(Locale.getDefault()) == "am"
            ) Calendar.AM else Calendar.PM
        return calendar
    }
```

Comment: Nothing obviously sticks out to me (you're calling some functions we can't see, and there are some mystery variables like ``durhrs`` that you're not calculating here?) so I'd recommend setting a breakpoint somewehere (like at the start of the ``for`` loop) and debugging it, step through and watch the values you're getting, and see where the logic is going wrong. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug if you've never used it - it's good to learn!

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: So, if I have 3 bookable slots for wednesday, say 8 am to 9 am, 9 am to 10.00 am and 10 am to 11.00 am, and the slot at 8 am is now booked, a new user needs to see only the 9 am and 10.00 am slot. But what happens is I see all three slots even if the 8.00 am slot is booked... which is weird... considering that the code seems sound...

Comment: The functions that not seen are two - createTime - converts 8.00 am in text to a calendar of 8.00 am and getting duration for the booked slot in hours and mins

Comment: Did you solve this? Share the code please